# pthread_cond_timedwait return ETIMEDOUT before real timeout in Android

Tags: android, c++, pthreads

I use pthread_cond_timewait to block a thread for given time or make it waiting a signal in Andorid native C++ code, below is my wait function. But in Android O, the wait function may return ETIMEDOUT too early, before the timeout. I do not understand why it happens.

```
int Wait(MutexLock& mutex, int64_t misc)
{
    int iret=-1; 
    if(misc<=0)
    {
        iret = pthread_cond_wait(&cond_, &mutex.get_pthread_mutex());
        return iret;
    }
    struct timespec ts;
    timeval now; 
    gettimeofday(&now,NULL);
    ts.tv_sec = now.tv_sec;
    ts.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;
    ts.tv_sec +=misc/1000;
    uint64_t cur_misc=ts.tv_nsec/1000000;
    uint64_t tmp_misc=cur_misc+misc%1000;
    ts.tv_sec +=tmp_misc/1000;
    ts.tv_nsec =(tmp_misc%1000)*1000000;   
    iret=pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond_, &mutex.get_pthread_mutex(), &ts);
    return iret;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is terminating early? how long is the timeout you are giving it? Also, what does strace say that your process is performing?

Comment: The error would be in errno(), return value just returns success or failure what is the errno()?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh, I set the timeout 5 seconds, from the log I can find it terminate early. I add log before and after the wait function call.

Comment: @SamerTufail, I print the error info with strerror(retCode), it is Connection timed out

Comment: @wqycsu, try to dump actual system calls with strace. Use attach if necessary.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh, I run this code in Android, and this problem occurs by chance, so it's difficult to dump the system call.

Comment: You don't need the dump when the problem occurs. Just to understand what actual system call takes place vs. what you think takes place. Also, if the problem happens by chance, maybe your timeout isn't what you claim it is (the code you posted does not contain the timeout).

Comment: @ShacharShemesh, the timeout is a constant (5s). I will try to dump the system call trace.

Comment: I find out the result of this problem, it's not because pthread_cond_timewait return early, but because the cpu sleep in Android, and it affects the code executing flow.